# getting the multiple max row using group by and having clause

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql> select * from raj;
+------+----------+
| id   | quantity |
+------+----------+
|    1 |      250 |
|    1 |      250 |
|    2 |      250 |
|    2 |      150 |
|    3 |      150 |
|    3 |      150 |
|    4 |      150 |
|    4 |      350 |
+------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id,sum(quantity)
    -> from raj
    -> group by(id);
```

**Question:**
from the above table i want to get the max quantity customer_id and quant
the output should look like

```
+------+---------------+
| id   | sum(quantity) |
+------+---------------+
|    1 |           500 |
|    
|    4 |           500 |
+------+---------------+
```

**What i have tried:**

```
select id,sum(quantity) quant
 from raj
 group by(id)
 having max(quant);
```

but the above query is giving empty set.
what i am doing wrong?

Comment: And the question is... ?

Comment: @zerkms edited my question.i want to fetch the max quantity row using group by and having

Comment: so you want it. Okay. What is your question?

Comment: `ORDER BY` + `LIMIT 1`

Comment: @zerkms i have clearly mentioned the question..

Comment: `ORDER BY` + `LIMIT 1`

Comment: @zerkms order by + limit 1 wont work.what if there are more than one record with max values

Comment: @zerkms m using group by so thats causing little bit of problem ,i have also shared what i have tried..please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so b using another query to get the maximum of sum and then use `HAVING` clause to match the maximum sum of your first query,so the query will return all the customers if there are more than 1 customers having same maximum quantity

```
SELECT id,
SUM(quantity) quant,t.max_sum
 from Table1
JOIN (SELECT SUM(quantity) max_sum 
      FROM Table1 
  GROUP BY id 
  ORDER BY max_sum DESC LIMIT 1) t
 GROUP BY id
HAVING quant = t.max_sum
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b7d5/5)

Answer (score 1):

```
select groups.*
from
     (select id,sum(quantity) quant
      from raj
      group by(id)) groups JOIN
     (select max(quant) as max_q
      from (select id,sum(quantity) quant
            from raj
            group by(id)) tmp
      ) max_data ON groups.quant=max_data.max_q
```